# normalized lower incomplete gamma in R

Tags: r, distribution, gamma-distribution

I am attempting to reproduce results of [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1057/jma.2014.3#Tab2) paper in R, but I am stuck on two parts.

1. plotting the normalized lower incomplete gamma functions
   [image]
2. calculating the loss function

[image]

This problem would be solved if there existed a function in R that computed the `normalized lower incomplete gamma function`. So my question is, how can I calculated the [normalized lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

Comment: "but I am stuck ..." How so? What have you tried? In any event, without reading whatever paper you are referring to, it is hard to know what all of this notation actually means. This question lacks context.

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman . I updated my question to one specific function.

Comment: The question is now sufficiently focused and already has a good, accepted, answer. I thus vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgamma` is the normalized lower incomplete gamma function, see `?pgamma`:

> pgamma is closely related to the incomplete gamma function. As defined
>   by Abramowitz and Stegun 6.5.1 (and by ‘Numerical Recipes’) this is
>
> P(a,x) = 1/Gamma(a) integral_0^x t^(a-1) exp(-t) dt

Comment: @Alex, well, it does allow for two parameters, try `pgamma(2, shape = 1, rate = 4)`.